# JpaPagingItemReader - endless Loop on failed read

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Hi I am getting endless loop when exception was thrown. 
Is there something wrong to the transactionmanager I am using?
Thanks!
Below is my job setup

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<Entity> bizAppReader() {
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    Map<String, Object> map  = new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
      put("status", Arrays.asList(new ApplicationStatus[] {ApplicationStatus.COMPLETED, ApplicationStatus.PENDING, ApplicationStatus.INITIATE}));
    }};

    return new JpaPagingItemReaderBuilder<Entity>()
        .name("bizAppJpaReader")
        .entityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory)
        .queryString("from Entity b where b.status in (:status)").parameterValues(map)
        .build();
  }

@Bean
public Step bizApplicatonStep(@Value("${batch.chunk_size:10}") int chunkSize,
      ItemReader<Entity> bizAppReader,
      ItemProcessor<Entity, Map<ApplicationStatus, String>> bizAppProcessor,
      ItemWriter<Map<ApplicationStatus, String>> bizAppWriter) {

    return stepBuilderFactory.get("bizApplicatonStep")
        .<Entity, Map<ApplicationStatus, String>>chunk(chunkSize).reader(bizAppReader)
        .processor(bizAppProcessor).writer(bizAppWriter)
        .faultTolerant()
          .skip(Exception.class)
          .noRollback(Exception.class)
          .skipPolicy((e, i) -> {
            log.error("Exception occurred : ", e);

            return true;
            })
          .allowStartIfComplete(true)
      .build();
  }

@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchApplication  extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(BatchApplication.class, args);

    JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
    Job job;
    JobParameters jobParameters;

    if (ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(args) && args[0].equals("bookingJob")) {
      job = context.getBean("bookingJob", Job.class);
      jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
        .addString("startMonth", args[1])
        .addString("endMonth", args[2])
        .toJobParameters();
    } else {
      job = context.getBean("bizApplicationJob", Job.class);
      jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().toJobParameters();
    }
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);

    if (BatchStatus.FAILED.equals(jobExecution.getStatus())) {
      log.error("job execution completed exit code is : 1 ");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    log.info("job execution completed exit code is : 0 ");
  }

  @Override
  protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
    return new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(new ResourcelessTransactionManager()).getObject();
  }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
10:13:20.657 [main] ERROR c.u.pweb.bizacct.batch.BizJobConfig - Exception occurred : 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction already active
   at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
```

-===================== Updated application to replicate =====================

this happen if the reader failed to read with invalid Enum value from DB.

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class DemoBatchApplication extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoBatchApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        super.setDataSource(null);
    }

    private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

  public DemoBatchApplication(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
  }

    @Override
  public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(this.entityManagerFactory);
  }

}
```

enum

```
public enum ApplicationStatus {
  MA, AS, SH, CP, AA, AP
}
```

table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APP_TBL_TEST")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
  @Column(name = "ID", length = 50)
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "APPLICATION_NAME", unique = true, length = 50)
  private String referenceNumber;

  @Column(name = "STATUS")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private ApplicationStatus status;

}
```

batch config

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@Data
public class ApplicationBatchCfg {

  @Autowired
  public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
  @Autowired
  public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
  @Autowired
  public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

  @Bean
  public Step applicationStep(@Value("${batch.chunk_size:5}") int chunkSize,
                              ItemReader<ApplicationEntity> appReader,
                              ItemProcessor<ApplicationEntity, String> appProcessor,
                              ItemWriter<String> appWriter){

    return stepBuilderFactory.get("applicatonStep")
      .<ApplicationEntity, String>chunk(chunkSize)
      .reader(appReader)
      .processor(appProcessor)
      .writer(appWriter)
      .faultTolerant()
      .skip(Exception.class)
      .noRollback(Exception.class)
      .skipPolicy((e, i) -> {
        log.error("Exception occurred : ", e);

        return true;
      })
      .skipLimit(5)
      .allowStartIfComplete(true)
      .build();

  }

  @Bean
  public Job applicationJob(Step applicationStep) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("applicationJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
      .start(applicationStep).build();
  }

  @Bean
  public ItemReader<ApplicationEntity> appReader() {
    return new JpaPagingItemReaderBuilder<ApplicationEntity>()
      .name("appReader")
      .entityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory)
      .queryString("from ApplicationEntity")
      .pageSize(3)
      .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public ItemProcessor<ApplicationEntity, String> appProcessor(){
    return new ItemProcessor<ApplicationEntity, String>() {
      @Override
      public String process(ApplicationEntity item) throws Exception {
        //nothing for demo only
        log.info("item {}", item);
        return null;
      }
    };
  }

  @Bean
  public ItemWriter<String> appWriter() {
    return new ItemWriter<String>() {
      @Override
      public void write(List<? extends String> items) throws Exception {
        //nothing for demo only
      }
    };
  }

}
```

inside yml

```
spring:
  jpa:
     properties:
       hibernate:
         show_sql: true
         use_sql_comments : true
         format_sql: true
         dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
  datasource:
    useWallet: false
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@DB12397:1521:azd
    platform: oracle
    username: user
    password: pwd
```

Comment: I can't give a precise answer without reproducing the issue. In regards to your question about the transaction manager, you need to use the `JpaTransactionManager` since you are using JPA.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Thank for your response, I have updated my post to replicate. I hope you can replicate in your local.. It start endless loop once it fails to read invalid Enum value from Database.

Comment: Please run your app with `--debug` flag and attach the full log with the full stacktrace. It is not possible to reproduce the issue with what you shared (missing dependencies in pom.xml or build.gradle, imports, need an oracle db..) so please share a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with an embedded db on github/gitlab and I will take a look.